# .NET 8 Blazor app just started throwing App error on Azure

Tags: blazor, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

Our .NET 8 application just started throwing a build error when deployed to Azure website. This has been working up last week, and is working OK in dev/locally.

Build error:

> The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found

To resolve the build error I added an empty `App.razor.cs` file. Now I get an application error (again, only on Azure not locally)

> This xxxxx.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found.
> No webpage was found for the web address:
> https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/

---

### Update - files as requested

**csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Reports\IcoReport.vsrepx" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Reports\IcoReport.vsrepx" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Redacted.MyAppName.API\Redacted.MyAppName.API.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Redacted.MyAppName.Model\Redacted.MyAppName.Model.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Redacted.MyAppName.Repository\Redacted.MyAppName.Repository.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Redacted.MyAppName.Shared.UI\Redacted.MyAppName.Shared.UI.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Redacted.Framework" Version="10.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Redacted.Framework.Web.Shared" Version="10.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Blazor" Version="23.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="6.0.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.SignalR" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="8.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\ServiceDependencies\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Application\Feature\Incidents\IncidentsPage.razor" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Application\Feature\Steps\ThingNotificationAdd - Copy.razor.cs">
        <DependentUpon>ThingNotificationAdd.razor.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Application\Feature\Steps\FollowUpVisitDetails - Copy.razor.cs">
        <DependentUpon>FollowUpVisitDetails.razor.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Reports\IcoReport.cs">
        <DependentUpon>IcoReport.vsrepx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Reports\IcoReport.Designer.cs">
        <DependentUpon>IcoReport.vsrepx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>


    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/Redacted/providers/microsoft.insights/components/my-app-name-insights-dev</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
        <DxExtendStartupHost>False</DxExtendStartupHost>
        <UserSecretsId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Claims;

using Redacted.Framework.Extensions;
using Redacted.Framework.Helpers;
using Redacted.Framework.Logging;
using Redacted.Framework.Repository;
using Redacted.Framework.Repository.Data;
using Redacted.Framework.Services;
using Redacted.Framework.Web.Shared.Components.Data;
using Redacted.MyAppName.Model.Auth;
using Redacted.MyAppName.Repository;
using Redacted.MyAppName.Shared.UI.Data;

using DevExpress.Blazor.Reporting;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

using Serilog;

namespace Redacted.MyAppName.Web.Admin
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            var assemblyName = assembly.GetAssemblyName();
            var assemblyVersion = assembly.GetAssemblyVersion();

            var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            Log.Logger = GenericLoggerConfiguration
                .GetSerilogConfiguration(environmentName)
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information(Constants.Logging.Messages.SERVICE_STARTED, assemblyName, assemblyVersion, environmentName);
                var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

                Console.WriteLine($"AssemblyName: {assemblyName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"AssemblyVersion: {assemblyVersion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"ApplicationName: {builder.Environment.ApplicationName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"EnvironmentName: {builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"ContentRootPath: {builder.Environment.ContentRootPath}");
                Console.WriteLine($"WebRootPath: {builder.Environment.WebRootPath}");

                builder.Host.UseSerilog();

                ConfigureServices(builder.Services, builder.Configuration);

                var app = builder.Build();
                ConfigureApp(app);

                using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Redacted.MyAppName.Repository.MyAppDbContext>();
                    context.Database.Migrate(); // apply outstanding migrations automatically
                }
                app.Run();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Don't log an error if running via EF CLI as this will always error when running a migration command
                if (ex is HostAbortedException && assemblyName == "ef") { return; }
                Log.Fatal(ex, Constants.Logging.Messages.SERVICE_STARTED_EXCEPTION, assemblyName);
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                // make sure all batched messages are written.
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager configuration)
        {
            services.AddSerilogServices(configuration);

            // Reporting
            services.AddDevExpressBlazorReporting();
            DevExpress.Utils.AzureCompatibility.Enable = true;

            // repository details for MyAppName
            services.AddScopedDataServices<MyAppDbContext>(configuration, "MyAppName");


            // register Azure AD, AddControllersWithViews(), AddAuthorization(), AddRazorPages() and AddServerSideBlazor()
            services.AddAzureAdServices(configuration,
                new KeyValuePair<string, AuthorizationPolicy>[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, AuthorizationPolicy>(Policies.IsMyAppSuperUser, Policies.IsMyAppSuperUserPolicy()),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, AuthorizationPolicy>(Policies.IsCurrentUser, Policies.IsCurrentUserPolicy())

                });

            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MatchingThingAuthorisationHandler>();
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MatchingUserEmailAuthorisationHandler>();

            // Redacted DI
            services.AddRedactedServices<MyAppDbContext>();

            services.AddScoped(typeof(ISimpleDataService<,>), typeof(SimpleDataService<,>));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IIncidentLetterService<>), typeof(IncidentLetterService<>));

            // ... a whole bunch of service scopes removed for brevity
            services.AddScoped<IThingNotificationService, ThingNotificationService>();
            services.AddScoped<IThingTagService, ThingTagService>();
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IAuditLogDataSearchService<>), typeof(AuditLogDataSearchService<>));
        
            // ClaimsPrincipal / CurrentUser
            services.AddScoped(sp =>
            {
                var provider = sp.GetService<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
                var state = provider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;
                return state.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? state.User : new ClaimsPrincipal();
            });

            services.AddDevExpressBlazor(configure => configure.SizeMode = DevExpress.Blazor.SizeMode.Large);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public static void ConfigureApp(WebApplication app)
        {
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-GB" };
            var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
                .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
                .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            // Redirects the user back to the index page when signed out
            app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
                .Add(context =>
                {
                    if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut")
                    { context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/"); }
                }));

            // Redirect back to index page for 404 status codes
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Add this line; you'll need `using Serilog;` up the top, too
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

            app.UseDevExpressBlazorReporting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAntiforgery();
            app.UseLoggingMiddleware();

            app.MapRazorPages();
            app.MapControllers();
            app.MapRazorComponents<Redacted.MyAppName.Web.Admin.App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` and `Program.cs` file

Comment: I know this is stating the obvious, but something you have changed has caused the problem.  Only you can determine what.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis yep I'm long enough in the tooth to know that is 99% likely, but so little code has changed in this release that its got my spidey sense tingling that something has changed in the pipeline, or azure platform that I've missed.

Comment: . . . and Git gets another new user.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 ?

Comment: I understand.  But you can only establish if something in the environment has changed and impacted you if the previous code that did work doesn't any more.  You need a base point to start from.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I ran the build from a previous successful commit and that is now also failing. Gah!

Comment: @MarkCooper - If possible can you please share your code repo?

Comment: How is your site deployed?   IIS server?

Comment: @MarkCooper - OK.  Have you tried to do a new deployment to a new Azure Web Site?  This sounds like something silly.   `MapRazorComponents` in the HttpRequest pipeline can't find `Redacted.MyAppName.Web.Admin.App`.

Comment: To those that might follow... the code that was failing is now working. Same commits, same pipeline. No idea what caused this, why it failed, or why it is now working. Sorry :-(